# Django forms: adding a 'new' option to a select field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, choicefield

I have the following two models: Invoice and Relation (foreign key to Invoice). When you create an Invoice you must select a Relation. I am currently building the forms and I wanted to know how I can add a 'new' options to my select field choices. The new option would allow the user to create a new relation if the relation did not already exist.

Comment: Follow this article or use the app provided in the end: http://sontek.net/blog/detail/implementing-djangos-admin-interface-pop-ups

Comment: Thanks arocks at first glance looks great. In depth also.

Comment: @arocks's link looks to be dead, but it's on the Wayback Machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140706232149/http://sontek.net/blog/detail/implementing-djangos-admin-interface-pop-ups)